# ValueError: [E966] `nlp.add_pipe` now takes the string name of the registered component factory, not a callable component

Tags: nlp, spacy

```
#Ejemplo: un componente simple (1)
# Crea el objeto nlp
nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm")

# Define un componente personalizado
def custom_component(doc):
    # Imprime la longitud del doc en pantalla
    print("longitud del Doc:", len(doc))
    # Devuelve el objeto doc
    return doc

# Añade el componente al primer lugar del pipeline
nlp.add_pipe(custom_component, first=True)

# Imprime los nombres de los componentes del pipeline
print("Pipeline:", nlp.pipe_names)
```

1. I tried but i got the error bellow in  **nlp.add_pipe(custom_component, first=True)**
2. How can I fixed please?

Answer (score 0):

Please read [the docs on custom components](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components). You have to do something like this.

```
from spacy.language import Language

@Language.component("my_component")
def my_component(doc):
   # Do something to the doc here
   return doc
```